# C# arrays minimal value in specific range

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, min

Everybody!
How can I get minimal value of an int array in specific range in C#?
For example:
int[] array= new int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,76,45};
And I want to get a minimal value between 3-rd and 8-th element.
Maybe it is possible to get via LINQ queries?

Comment: Will it always have at least 8 elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
array.Skip(2).Take(5).Min();
```

Comment: @nozim: No, it's not because it's not immediately clear what it's doing. It's clever, and it looks clever, but it's not the most readable solution and thus should be rejected. Sorry.

Comment: @Jason: skip 2 items, take 5 items, then get the min.  whats not clear?

Comment: @poindexter12: Look, it's clear that it's doing that. It's not clear that it's finding the minimum of the elements whose index is between 2 and 7, inclusive. This solution makes that more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412596/c-arrays-minimal-value-in-specific-range/4412609#4412609

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I feel the point is being missed here, especially if you disagree. Yes it's understandable that it's skipping two, taking five and finding the min. What is not clear is that it is solving the problem at hand. It takes a moment of thought (albeit small) to see that whereas the solution I previously pointed to does not. I feel this is getting voted for because of the cleverness factor (and clever code is bad!).

Comment: @Jason: I feel this is simpler to understand than Thomas's approach. The use of `Skip` and `Take` make it immediately clear that the *values* of the elements aren't relevant to the filtering... whereas the more general `Where` clause forces the reader to consider carefully exactly what's going on. Note that for an array of integers, it would also be easy to get the `value` and `index` parameters the wrong way round accidentally. If you want to make it more "start" and "end" related, then Eric's approach is a good option.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: How is it possibly simpler? The problem asked for the minimum over the third to eighth elements. Thomas' code says "grab those items whose index is between two and seven (corresponding to the third through eighth elements) and take the minimum." This code says "skip the first two items, then take five, then take the minimum." Thomas' code reads exactly like the problem statement whereas this code takes a moment of thought to realize it has that behavior.

Comment: @Jason - Quite frankly the answer @Thomas posted has way too much noise. This answer reads to me like this: *"Given a sequence of integers, skip the first 2 elements, then take the minimum of the following 5 elements."* OK so it doesn't read exactly as the OP posted but that doesn't mean it is less clear.

Comment: @Jason: No, Thomas's code says, "Compare each pair of value and index. If the index is greater than 7 and less than or equal to 8, include this in the filtered sequence. Now take the minimum of that filtered sequence." It's the fact that `Where` *forces* you to consider the value as well as the index which makes me consider it less simple than the `Skip`/`Take` approach. Additionally, using Skip followed by `Take` makes it abundantly clear that this is just dealing with one block of values - not ones satisfying an arbitrary condition.

Comment: @Jason: Finally, using a `Where` clause here forces *every pair* to be evaluated - which makes it potentially much less efficient than the Skip/Take solution. If there are a million items in the array, it needs to consider them all... instead of just skipping some, taking what's needed, and then moving on.

Comment: @Jon - OK... so you are preaching to the choir here but that is some damn good preaching. :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I agree with your last comment concerning performance, but that's not what I was discussing. However, if that's what we're going to discuss, then the `Skip / Take` solution is inferior to `int min = Int32.MaxValue; for(int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) { if(array[i] < min) { min = a[i]; } }` by a mile. `Skip` will still call `IEnumerator<int>.MoveNext()` until it has skipped the appropriate number of elements (unless there's a special case to handle `int[]` that I'm not aware of).

Comment: @Jason: Yes, indeed it is (at least at the moment). But it's still better for performance than the argument you were championing :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Now to reply to your penultimate comment, it's the inclusion of the index that makes it more clear to me. And I don't see the problem with including the value. Again, slightly rewording what I had before, but I think carrying exactly the same meaning, Thomas' code says "grab those values whose index is between two and seven and take the minimum." The values are important because that's what we're finding the minimum of. We're finding the minimum of those values with a certain property. What property? That their index is between two and seven. That's what the `Where` says.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But I am not (giving up yet, ha!) championing it because of it's performance. Readability and semantics first, then performance (if it's important).

Comment: @Jason: No, we're *not* finding the minimum of *values* with a certain property. The values are integers - they don't have indexes. The *sequence elements* have indexes, but the value that's referred to by the `value` variable in Thomas's answer is just an integer. If you're going to overload the word "value" to mean "entry in a sequence" and "the value of an entry in a sequence" then you've got a bigger hill to climb in persuading us that you're arguing for simplicity, IMO :) (Any comments on my answer, btw?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry, didn't see that you answered until you pointed it out here (which I then went and commented on). I think we're going to have to agree to disagree on which is better between `Skip / Take` and Thomas' solution though. I like what you did because it makes it readable like the problem statement. If performance is a concern, then you have to (for now) use the `for` loop implementation like I provided.

Comment: FWIW, the meaning of @decyclone's code is immediately clear to me, and I don't know anything about LINQ. To me it looks clean and elegant, not just "clever". Note that I'm not comparing this answer with any of the other answers, just looking at it in isolation.

Comment: By modifying this solution slightly, you could make it a bit clearer: `array.Take(7).Skip(2).Min()`. OK, it's a bit weird to have the Take before the Skip, but that way you can use the end index rather than the count...

Comment: @Thomas: That's neat... I like that idea a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

I figure I may as well add my tuppence to this. As Jason objects to the fact that we're saying how many we're skipping rather than the end index, we can add a simple extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WithIndexBetween<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    int startInclusive, int endExclusive)
{
    // The two values can be the same, yielding no results... but they must
    // indicate a reasonable range
    if (endExclusive < startInclusive)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endExclusive");
    }
    return source.Skip(startInclusive).Take(endExclusive - startInclusive);
}
```

Then:

```
int min = array.WithIndexBetween(2, 7).Min();
```

Adjust the extension method name to taste. (Naming is hard, and I'm not going to spend ages coming up with a nice one here :)

Comment: Yes, it's good because now it reads like the problem statement. Note that it reads as "takes those values in the sequence with index between two and seven, inclusive, and take the minimum" which is how Thomas' reads to me which is why I preferred it in the first place. So, I like this.

Comment: I was about to update my answer with something similar, then I saw your answer...

Comment: Jon, this is Awesome! I love extension methods. And Jason, I like your persistence and that too against Jon Skeet! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
int min = array.Where((value, index) => index >= 2 && index <= 7).Min();
```

---

EDIT

Actually, the approach above is quite inefficient, because it enumerates the whole sequence, even though we're not interested in items with an index higher than 7. A better solution would be to use `TakeWhile`:

```
int min = array.TakeWhile((value, index) => index <= 7).Skip(2).Min();
```

Unfortunately it's not very readable... The best option to make it nicer is probably to create a custom extension method, as shown in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int start = 3;
int end = 8;
int min = arr.Skip(start - 1).Take(end - start).Min();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option:

```
int start = 3;
int end = 8;
var min = Enumerable.Range(start - 1,end - start).Select(idx => array[idx]).Min();
```

AFAIK, this is "theorically" faster if you have to take a range near to the end of the one, and your array is really really long.

That's because (again AFAIK) `Skip()` doesn't take into account that is an array (i.e. can be accessed randomly in O(1)) and enumerates it anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's faster in the specific case of using an array (or other `IList<T>`) - but of course it falls apart in the general sequence case. Of course, `Skip` might be fixed in a future release, too :)

Comment: Of course, and I really hope it will be fixed. In the meanwhile mine was just a sort of warning :)

Comment: +1 for the warning, even though it's not the solution I'd usually pick :)

Answer (score 0):

```
array.Skip(3).Take(4).Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd prefer this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions {
    public static bool ArrayAndIndexesAreValid(
        T[] array,
        int startInclusive,
        int endExclusive
    ) {
    return array != null &&
           array.Length > 0 &&
           startInclusive >= 0 && startInclusive < array.Length &&
           endExclusive >= 1 && endExclusive <= array.Length &&
           startInclusive < endExclusive;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> Slice<T>(
        this T[] array,
        int startInclusive,
        int endExclusive
    ) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(ArrayAndIndexesAreValid(
            array,
            startInclusive,
            endExclusive)
        );
        for (int index = startInclusive; index < endExclusive; index++) {
            yield return array[index];
        }
    }
    public static T MinimumInIndexRange<T>(
        this T[] array,
        int startInclusive,
        int endExclusive
    ) where T : IComparable {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(ArrayAndIndexesAreValid(
            array,
            startInclusive,
            endExclusive)
        );
        return array.Slice(startInclusive, endExclusive).Min();
    }

    public static T MaximumInIndexRange<T>(
        this T[] array,
        int startInclusive,
        int endExclusive
    ) where T : IComparable {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(ArrayAndIndexesAreValid(
            array,
            startInclusive,
            endExclusive)
        );
        return array.Slice(startInclusive, endExclusive).Max();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will return `int.MaxValue` if the slice contains no elements, which probably isn't a good idea. It's also mixing the logic for "finding the minimum value" and "considering a slice of the array" which the LINQ-based solutions don't. If you need to find the *maximum* value of an array slice, you'll be repeating all that slicing logic.

Comment: By not making it generic, you've also forced yourself to reimplement it if you need the minimum value from a `long[]` etc. Making this operation generic is a no-brainer IMO. Of course, it's hard to do that while you're going to return a value for an empty array slice...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It throws on empty (which might not be preferred; see the second `Contract.Requires`). I'll respond to your second comment in a minute.

Comment: @Jason: Ah, the endIndex is inclusive. I hadn't expected that. (That's why my method's parameters make it explicit :) Generally speaking, methods expressing a min and max value (e.g. `Random.Next`) use an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound.

Comment: @Jason: When it's *so* easy to separate the concerns of slicing and max/min, and *also* very easy to make it generic, I don't think YAGNI really applies. It's hardly over-engineering to use a generic method where it's obviously a generic algorithm. I'm still not convinced that putting the two aspects in the same method call is a great idea. Maybe if you're doing this over and over again... but otherwise, use composition of simple operations at the client side.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yeah, that's fair. I've edited to address your concerns. No reimplementing of the minimum value from a `long[]`, no need to reimplement the slicing for computing a maximum value, etc. Since empty sequences don't have a minimum value (definition of minimum of a sequence is value `v` __in the sequenece__ such that `v <= w` for all other values `w` in the sequence; here, `<=` is a generic total ordering) we should throw on that case. If one is so inclined, they can include an overload with a default value to use as a minimum / maximum in case of an empty array.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You caught me; I erased my comment about YAGNI after I gave it some further thought but before I saw your comment. I completely agree with you, making this generic is not even close to overengineering.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So you're suggesting don't bother with the `MinimumInIndexRange` and `MaximumInIndexRange` methods, but instead just the `Slice` and have the client say `array.Slice(startInclusive, endExclusive).Min()`? I think it depends; if this were in my code over and over I'd prefer to have the methods. Is there a good reason to not in that case?

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that's what I'd do. Given that LINQ already provides Min and Max, why reinvent the wheel? It's easier to learn a few methods and then combine them in the calling code than learn each separate combination as a separate method.